# My Graph ADT's addVertex method will accept normal integers but not integers when passed through for loops, why is this?

Tags: c++, algorithm, github, graph, abstract-class

I'm doing a graph ADT https://github.com/atomind2005/Vectors-Graph-Theory-Implementation
When I run graph.addVertex(0), graph.addVertex(1), etc all the way to graph.addVertex(9), it works, but when I run

```
for(int x =0; x < 10; x++){
graph.addVertex(x);
}
```

however big the number may be on the for loop, it always throws a segmentation fault. I have no clue why this is happening, please help
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Run your code with a debugger to find out where and what the segmentation fault is happening

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem.

This test passes

```
void testforloop()
{
    Graph graph;
    // Test adding vertices using for loop https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316586/16582
    std::cout << "\nfor loop test\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        graph.addVertex(x);
    }
    // 99 vertices expected because the vertex '0' is rejected
    if( graph.returnVertices() != 99 )
        throw std::runtime_error("for loop test failed");
    std::cout << "for loop test PASSED\n";
}
```

Notes:

1 There is not a single comment in any of your code.  It will be very hard to maintain!

2 Searching through the entire graph every time you add a node is going to be very slow for large graphs.  This code will be unusable for graphs of more than 100 nodes.

3 Doing an `insert` on a vector is also horribly inefficient.  Suppose you have a graph of 100 nodes and decide to insert a node with the index value of 1.  This needs to be inserted at the beginning of the vector and EVERY SINGLE other node in the graph will have to moved.